# Does normalizing image data cause the model to ignore colors?

Tags: image-processing

After deducting by the images mean and standard deviation, most of the differences between wildly different pixel values of images should be very small. I understand this is to prevent certain image colours (e.g. background colours that are very dark) to sway the representation of an image.

However, would this also mean normalization is effectively casting off the information in the colour of the object to be classified? What is the benefit of ignoring what the colors of an image are?

Comment: Yes, it would do something terrible to the image as it is a range adjustment of grey scale not color. What you want is a [more comprehensive color normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_normalization#Comprehensive_Color_Normalization).

Comment: While @Carl is correct that the colors will look funky after simple linear scaling (and that this isn't the greatest method for normalization), that doesn't mean the model will ignore colors.  You will still have a distribution of intensities and the intensities will make different combinations in different images so the color information isn't gone, just changed.  However, since it is unlikely that colors will map well between images, you will have to do something like binning to make the colors meaningful for ML.